# Can Qt Creator in Linux create executables for Windows?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Can I create executables for Windows using Qt Creator in Linux? Or would I have to use a cross-compiler?

I'm guessing Qt Creator in Linux has an option to build code for Windows. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 4):

Qt Creator is just an IDE it does not necessarily come with a compiler, though it can be set up to use various compilers like the GCC or a cross compiler.

You can compile applications for windows on linux using a cross compiler.  One such cross compiler is the [Minimalist GNU win32 (cross) compiler](http://www.mingw.org/) in which case [this link](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW) will should be useful to you.  It would probably be safe to assume that most distro's have a packaged version which you can use. If they do use that instead, usually searching the package management system for 'mingw' is enough to find it.